# Static initialization in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++-cli

Hi, all!

I'm developing winForm app on visual C++ (managed code).
This app link native static library which contain block of code with static variable initialization:

#### Cls.h

```
class Cls
{
public:
    static Cls* getInstance();

private:
    static Cls _instance;
protected:
    Cls(void);
};
```

#### Cls.cpp

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "Cls.h"

Cls::Cls(void)
{
}

Cls Cls::_instance;

Cls* Cls::getInstance()
{
    return &_instance;
}
```

I can link those library successfully, but when I try to use *getInstance()* method I get a run-time error before invoke main function of my app.

It's a third party library, so I cannot rebuild it or redefine *Cls* class on any other way.

App project uses */clr*, entry point defined as *main*.

I tired to search a solution. I found that I must change entry point, but I don't know what value would be correct.

Please, help!

Comment: I would suggest to try and see if the value is correct instead of speculating that the value may not be correct.

Comment: At which point do you call `getInstance()`? During initialization, or later?

Answer (score 4):

You're encountering the notorious "static initialisation order fiasco". When static objects are defined in two translation units, it's unspecified which is initialised first; so, if the constructor of one refers to the other, you could end up accessing it before it is initialised. The only guarantee is that they will all be initialised before `main` begins.

The best solution is to avoid static objects. In particular, the Singleton anti-pattern that you are using is rather tricky to get right in C++, and is generally more trouble than it's worth.

If you really want to do this, then you can work around the fiasco by defining the static object inside a function:

```
Cls* Cls::getInstance()
{
    static Cls _instance;
    return &_instance;
}
```

This has the disadvantage that it introduces a "destruction order fiasco" (where it might not be safe to access from the destructor of another static object), and that it might not be thread-safe in some compilers (although it should be in any that claims C++11 compliance). If construction is thread-safe, then there will be a (small) runtime cost for each access, which might be a problem if you have extreme performance issues.

UPDATE: I've just noticed that you say that this evil class is outside your control and can't be changed. In that case, your options are:

- Get rid of this library and use something less insane, or
- Be careful not to access any of its static data until `main` has begun; in particular, follow my advice above and avoid any static objects of your own.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `static Cls _instance;`?

Comment: @Fiktik: Thanks, I didn't spot that. In that case, options are limited.